# Leetcode 004 Median of Two Sorted Arrays. Is expected answer wrong?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, median

Base on the [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/) that need to find the median of the two sorted arrays.

So i test some sample :

(1)

[1,2] [3,4]

-> Merge and sorted = [1,2,3,4] median is (2+3)/2 = 2.5

Expected answer = 2.5, that correct

(2)

[1,2,0,0] [3,4]

-> Merge and sorted = [0,0,1,2,3,4] median is (1+2)/2 = 1.5

But why "Expected answer" = 0.0 ??

(3)

[0,0,1] [0,1]

-> Merge and sorted = [0,0,0,1,1] median is just 0

But why "Expected answer" = 1.0 ??

Comment: It appears to me you need not sort the array, only merge it. But then it is not median anymore. And array 1 in example 2 is not sorted.

Comment: Hi, if only merge , for example 2 array [1,5,6,7,8,9][2,3,4]
only merge = [1,5,6,7,8,9,2,3,4] ,and the median = 8
But why "Expected answer" = 5

Comment: Just concatenate the two arrays and calculate the median. ie `[1,2,0,0] [3,4] => [1,2,0,0,3,4] => M=(0+0)/2=0`, `[0,0,1] [0,1] => [0,0,1,0,1] => M=1`. Make any sense? Maybe not, but gives the expected answer...